# How to format short date using momentJS?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm receiving date from an endpoint in the following format: `yymmdd`

Example: `210626`

What I need is to change the format to `DD/MM/YYYY` maybe using momentJS or something else.

I tried several momentJS methods and some custom function I didn't came up with any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With moment is pretty easy

```
moment("210626", "YYMMDD").format("DD/MM/YYYY")
//"26/06/2021"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend `format` method from the `date-fns` for such purpose

https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/format

In overall `date-fns` is much lighter than `momentJS` and switching on it in your projects may be a good idea.